# Counting how much specific characters are in a string is not working properly

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, character

The assignment I am working on is asking me to input a number `N`, and then to input `N` strings and to check how many characters `'a'` `'e'` `'i'` `'o'` `'u'` and `'A'` `'E'` `'I'` `'O'` `'U'` are in each string and then to print it out. However, when the last string in the array starts with one of those characters, the program won't count the first letter of it, for some reason.

For example, this input:

```
3
This is a test
Hey Joe
I like pancakes
```

will have the output:

```
4
3
5
```

instead of:

```
4
3
6
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N,i,j,brojac=0;
    vector<string> recenice;
    string pom;
    cin>>N;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, pom);
        recenice.push_back(pom);
    }

    for(i=0;i<recenice.size();i++){
            for(j=0;j<recenice[i].size();j++){
                if(recenice[i][j]=='a' || recenice[i][j]=='e' || recenice[i][j]=='i' || recenice[i][j]=='o' || recenice[i][j]=='u' || recenice[i][j]=='A' || recenice[i][j]=='E' || recenice[i][j]=='I' || recenice[i][j]=='O' || recenice[i][j]=='U') ++brojac;
            }
            cout<<brojac<<endl<<endl;
            brojac=0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What is the cause of the counter not counting the first character of the last string if it fulfills the condition?

Comment: What would you guess that `cin.ignore();` does?

Comment: So when i use getline it doesn't work properly so i figured cin ignore is needed then, however is it making the problem here?

Comment: oof fixed it when i erased cin.ignore(); from the for function and wrote it above the for function, thanks

Comment: There you go! The `getline()` function *consumes* the 'trailing' newline character; but you should have it before the `for` loop, as `cin >> N` doesn't do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ --- getline, and cin ignore () .deleting first characters in strings on output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270376/c-getline-and-cin-ignore-deleting-first-characters-in-strings-on-outp)